# What is the problem with the replace function?

Tags: python-3.x

The assignment is just to convert :) to  and :(  to  and I have to implement two functions convert and main. I don't understand the problem with ".replace" it gets never coloured.

```
def convert(str):
    str = str.replace(":)","")
    str = str.replace(":(","")
   
def main():
    str = input("write something: ")
    convert(str)
    print(str)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, and you ignore the return value anyway. Strings are _immutable_.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do

```py
def convert(input_string: str) -> str:
    return_value = input_string.replace(":)","").replace(":(","")
    return return_value
def main() -> None:
    _str = input("write something: ")
    ret = convert(_str)
    print(ret)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` the updated value, and assign the string to the returned value:

```
def convert(s):
    s = s.replace(":)", "")
    s = s.replace(":(", "")
    # Make sure to return the updated variable to the caller
    return s


def main():
    x = input("write something: ")
    # Make x = [the returned value from convert]
    x = convert(x)
    print(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And try to avoid using `str` as a variable name, as it is the name of a Python class